# dropdown list not shown in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, list

I've got problem with dropdown list. 
i want to show a primary key as a dropdown list in view blade , but i can not make the right rout to show it. Have you any ideas how to solve this problem?

this my root

```
  $objects = ['users', 'permissions', 'roles', 'coins','pillars','subtindicators'];

    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        Route::get("$object", ucfirst(str_singular($object))."Controller@index")->middleware("permission:browse $object")->name("{$object}");
         Route::get("$object/datatable", ucfirst(str_singular($object))."Controller@datatable")->middleware("permission:browse $object")->name("{$object}.datatable");
        Route::get("$object/add", ucfirst(str_singular($object))."Controller@add")->middleware("permission:add $object")->name("{$object}.add");
          Route::post("$object/create", ucfirst(str_singular($object))."Controller@create")->middleware("permission:add $object")->name("{$object}.create");
        Route::get("$object/{id}/edit", ucfirst(str_singular($object))."Controller@edit")->middleware("permission:edit $object")->name("{$object}.edit");
        Route::post("$object/{id}/update", ucfirst(str_singular($object))."Controller@update")->middleware("permission:edit $object")->name("{$object}.update");
        Route::get("$object/{id}/delete", ucfirst(str_singular($object))."Controller@delete")->middleware("permission:delete $object")->name("{$object}.delete");
        Route::get("$object/{id}", ucfirst(str_singular($object))."Controller@view")->middleware("permission:view $object")->name("{$object}.view");
        Route::get("$object/create", ucfirst(str_singular($object))."Controller@list")->middleware("permission:add $object")->name("{$object}.create");
```

this my controller

```
public function add()
  {        $strs = DB::table('stargets')->select('*')->get();;
          return view('subtindicators.add-edit',compact('strs'));

   }

  public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $object = $this->objectModel::find($id);
        $object->update([
          'skey_name' => $request->skey_name,
          'Subtarget_base' => $request->Subtarget_base,
          'Subtarget_end' => $request->Subtarget_end,
          'subtarget_id' => $request->subtarget_id
        ]);


        if ($request->save == 'browse')
            return redirect()->route("{$this->objectName}");
        elseif ($request->save == 'edit')
            return redirect()->route("{$this->objectName}.edit", ['id' => $object]);
        elseif ($request->save == 'add')
          return redirect()->route("{$this->objectName}.add");
                 else
            return redirect($request->previous_url);
    }
```

this my blade

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

@include('bread.title')

@section('main-content')
    <div class="container-fluid spark-screen">
        <div class="row">

                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{$actionName=='edit'?route("{$objectName}.update",['id'=>$object->id]):route("{$objectName}.create") }}" method="post">
                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <input type="hidden" name="previous_url" value="{{ url()->previous() }}">
                                        <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ $actionName == 'edit' ? route("{$objectName}.update", ['id' => $object->id]) : route("{$objectName}.create") }}" method="post">
                                            {!! csrf_field() !!}


                                            <input type="hidden" name="previous_url" value="{{ url()->previous() }}">
                                            <div class="box box-solid">
                                                <div class="box-header with-border">
                                                    <h3 class="box-title">{{ ucfirst($actionName) }} {{ ucfirst($objectName) }} {{ !empty($object) ? "(ID $object->id)" : '' }}</h3>
                                                    <div class="box box-solid">
                                                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                                                            <h3 class="box-title">{{ ucfirst($actionName) }} {{ ucfirst($objectName) }} {{ !empty($object) ? "(ID $object->id)" : '' }}</h3>
                                                            <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                </div>
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-2 control-label">col</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" name="skey_name" class="form-control" maxlength="255" value="{{ !empty($object) ? $object->coin_arname : '' }}" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-2 control-label">cl_d</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" name="Subtarget_base" class="form-control" maxlength="255" value="{{ !empty($object) ? $object->coin_enname : '' }}" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="col-md-2 control-label">cl_e</label>
                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                    <input type="text" name="Subtarget_end" class="form-control" maxlength="255" value="{{ !empty($object) ? $object->coin_arsymbol : '' }}" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="" class="form-control">c_i</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                                                    <select class="form-control" name="starget_id">
                                                                                <option selected disabled value = " ">choos</option>
                                                                @foreach($strs as $vis)
                                                                <option value="{{$vis->id}}">{{$vis->target_name}}</option>
                                                                @endforeach
                                                            <!--      <p class="form-control-static">{{ $object->subtarget_id }}</p>-->
                                                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                                                                                    <label for="title">main<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                                                         <select class="form-control" name="starget_id">
                                                                                            <option selected disabled value = " ">choos</option>
                                                                                    @foreach($strs as $slider2)
                                                                                    <option value="{{$slider2->id}}" {{ $slider2->id== $slider->starget_id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$slider2->vname}}</option>
                                                                                    @endforeach
                                                                                       </div>

                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                <div class="box-footer">
                                                        @include('bread.add-edit-actions')
                                                </div>
                    </div>

    </form>        </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

this error what i got

> ErrorException (E_ERROR)
>   Undefined variable: actionName (View: C:\project Last\resources\views\bread\title.blade.php) (View: C:\Ministry Last\resources\views\bread\title.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should forward `$actionName` variable to your view:

```
public function add()
{       
   $strs = DB::table('stargets')->select('*')->get();
   $actionName = 'edit';
   return view('subtindicators.add-edit',compact('strs', 'actionName'));
}
```

However this will hardcode the form to being an "edit" form. You must see what you really want with your logic.